# How to disable mouse event on certain elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I wrote a canvas js from scratch which creates bubbles on mouse events. Now my page has few elements/buttons. Even when I am hovering them my canvas generates bubbles, how can I stop from sending mouse events on particular elements. Note that I have on hover effects on those buttons, not sure if it matters though. I really appreciate any help, as I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: could you please share your code here to understand what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a minimal example so we know exactly what you're talking about.  Preferably use the `<>` button in the toolbar (next to the images) so you can edit HTML, CSS, and JS while also producing the result in an iframe.

I'll come back and edit this answer once you've done this, here is an example of what we need to see (hit "Run Code Snippet" to see the iframe):

```js
//Preparing canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
let fullWidth = canvas.width;
let fullHeight = canvas.height;

//utiliy functions
function isArray(object) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(object) == "[object Array]";
}

function isNumber(object) {
    return typeof object == "number";
}

function random(min, max) {
    if (isArray(min)) return min[~~(Math.random() * min.length)];
    if (!isNumber(max)) (max = min || 1), (min = 0);
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

//Circle class for circle objects
class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, radius) {
        this.alive = true;

        this.radius = radius;
        this.wander = 0.15;
        this.theta = random(2 * Math.PI);
        this.drag = 0.92;
        this.color = "#092140";

        this.x = x || 0.0;
        this.y = y || 0.0;

        this.vx = 0.0;
        this.vy = 0.0;
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }

    move() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;

        this.vx *= this.drag;
        this.vy *= this.drag;

        this.theta += random(-0.5, 0.5) * this.wander;
        this.vx += Math.sin(this.theta) * 0.1;
        this.vy += Math.cos(this.theta) * 0.1;

        this.radius *= 0.95;
        this.alive = this.radius > 0.5;
        this.draw();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.classList[0])
    if (event.target.classList[0] !== "fab"
        && event.target.id !== "social"
        && event.target.classList[0] !== "buttons-ul"
        && event.target.classList[0] !== "resume-li"
        && event.target.classList[0] !== "portf-btn") {
        
        let nx = event.x;
        let ny = event.y;
        console.log(nx + ", " + ny);

        init(nx, ny, 40);
        init(nx + random(5, 10), ny+random(5, 10), 40);
        init(nx + random(5, 15), ny+random(5, 15), 35);
    }
});

const circles = {};

// const COLORS = ["#004B8D", "#0074D9", "#4192D9", "#7ABAF2", "#D40D12", "#FF1D23"];

const COLORS = [
  '#E3F2FD', '#BBDEFB', '#90CAF9', '#64B5F6', '#42A5F5', '#2196F3', '#1E88E5', '#1976D2', '#1565C0', '#0D47A1', // Blue 50->900
  '#FFF8E1', '#FFECB3', '#FFE082', '#FFD54F', '#FFCA28', '#CC3B58', '#C93A29', '#FF3932', '#ED2938', '#C03A4C' // Amber 50->900
];

let key = 0;

function updateKey() {
    key++;
    key = key % 3000;
}

function init(x, y, maxRadius) {
    let circle, theta, force;

    circle = new Circle(x, y, random(10, maxRadius));
    circle.wander = random(0.5, 2.0);
    circle.drag = random(0.9, 0.99);
    theta = random(2 * Math.PI);
    force = random(2, 8);
    circle.vx = Math.sin(theta) * force;
    circle.vy = Math.cos(theta) * force;
    circle.color = random(COLORS);
    circles[key] = circle;
    updateKey();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    for (let k in circles) {
        if (!circles[k].alive) {
            delete circles[k];
        } else {
            circles[k].move();
        }
    }
}

animate();
```

```css
#root {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
}

#myCanvas {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root" class="fab">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" class="drawable" width="200" height="200">
  
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Sure, here is an example. 
I am sorry, I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have actually solved it with JS, but would appreciate if there is any other way. 

Please check out my github link, this is my JS canvas animation. Now imagine I have other elements in the page, such as buttons and some text. I want to stop that animation when I am on top of those elements. https://rpaltayev.github.io/js-canvas/

Now, in my solution there is an if condition inside mouselistener recall function, which checks if I am on that element or not. Is there other way to solve it?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how to solve the issue, especially since you've got a lot of code there already.  There are definitely plenty of ways to improve your code, one such way would be to LOOK FOR a class on your canvas, rather than looking for the LACK OF a certain classes like you're currently doing.  I added "fab" to the root element for my demo but if you plan on having tons of different classes and elements you'll definitely want to just check in the if statement whether the thing being scrolled over has a certain class, not whether it doesn't have as this solution wont scale well.

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe using same classes, or something. You can use event.stopPropagation();